# Why does lightoom 6 not keep my custom crop size

Tags: lightroom, aspect-ratio

Why does lightoom 6 not keep my custom crop size. I want to print A1 (841mmx594m) size so I set an equivalent custom aspect ratio (8.41 x 5.94) and that worked okay. But then I realized I needed a 5mm per side bleed (51mmx604mm) so I changed aspect ratio to 8.51 x 604, but Lightroom keeps changing it to 7 x 5. Now whilst very similar 7x 5 is not the same ratio as 8.51 x 6.04, i.e 851/7 = 121.57, whereas 604/5 = 120.8, so if I multiple 7 and 5 by the lower ratio I get 845.6 x 604 so Ive lost 5.5mm from the landscape length

Why does it do this ?

**Edit**
I wonder if it just accurate to two decimal places and doesn't round up, so these are the dimensions

841/594 = 1.4158
851/604 = 1.4089
7/5     = 1.40

and as you can see the last two are the same to two decimal places if don't round up, but they are different if I do round up.

If I set the aspect to 1 x 1.41 then Lightroom doesn't change it to 7x5, and I think this is close enough as 1 x 1.41 is the same as 851.64 x 604

Answer (score 2):

This has been a [known problem](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/i_cant_add_certain_custom_crop_ratios_in_lightroom) in Lightroom for over 2 years, with no response from Adobe.

I'm not sure what the precision is, but if you're too close to a standard aspect ratio it just uses the standard ratio.  I needed to do a 13x10 crop and LR refused to store it as a custom ratio, always choosing 8½x11 instead.   Curiously, 8½x11 is 1.29412 so 2 decimal places should have been enough to differentiate between the two.  It's not clear what's going on under the covers.

According to one comment on the Adobe forum from 2 years ago, older versions (LR3 and before) don't exhibit this behavior.

Comment: thankyou foir alerting me that its a known problem, shame noone knows exactly what the problem is though